# Microsoft Asp.net 5 DNX runtime version is still in beta?

Tags: release, asp.net-core, beta, dnx, dnvm

I'm bit confused, hope anyone clarify me. 
I'm Currently working in Asp.Net 5. Most of the DLL's and Framework are in **beta** as mentioned below. 
Can we start developing an app using this beta version? Can we move the code to production which we built in beta, Is it safe or do we have to wait until it gets released?

- DNX: dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-**beta8-15553**

Sample Dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
      "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta5",
      "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta5"
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

The ASP.NET 5 team just made [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/09/02/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta7.aspx) announcement to make Beta 7 available. This is the current stable version that most people should be using.

The Beta 8 version that you have listed looks like a nightly build. It will be unstable and some thing's might not work properly.

The choice of which version you use is up to you but I personally stick to the stable versions. As for moving your code to production, it's not entirely safe to do so yet. It's Beta for a reason, some thing's still aren't 100% there and some things are still just missing. However, if you are going to production in a few months time then you can consider using ASP.NET 5.

Comment: [ASP.NET 5 Schedule & Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap) and [Announcements](https://github.com/aspnet/announcements/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=) of breaking changes are useful pages.  beta8 is scheduled for release in early October.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed Thanks. We are going to start developing the new website app after a month now we are in the stage of collecting requirement and choosing right technologies. Because once we start working with the ASP.Net 5 beta version then our developers have to spend some time to upgrade the version on weekly basis. This will include in time line(i.e. estimate) right?

Comment: If you stick to the stable betas, you won't have to upgrade that often. There are however, missing features and third party libraries you might miss.

Comment: Thanks Rehan. @jiltrem thanks for the roadmap and breaking changes It helps me lot.